# How to search the name starting with special character in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have names which starts with special characters.I want to list those names. Some of the names are `'%faf yf? -s_'`, `'%faO{','%]fac?)f'` and so on.

My query to list the name starting from '%' is like this:

```
Select * from table where name like '%fa%';
```

This query is not working and it is also listing the names which starts from 'fa'. I only need the values which start from '%fa'.
I also tried the query like this

```
Select * from table where name like'[%]fa%'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `%`:

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

> To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash but a different one can be selected by using the ESCAPE clause. To match the escape character itself, write two escape characters

```
Select * 
from the_table 
where name like'\%fa%' escape '\'
```